# Django Tests Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I ran Django Tests using the command manage.py test myApp. I disabled south inorder to give tests to create data in the db. The tests.py contains only the following.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_basic_addition(self):
        """
        Tests that 1 + 1 always equals 2.
        """
        self.assertEqual(1 + 1, 2)
```

The output comes out to be the following.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: perhaps myApp isn't included in the INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: No its included in the settings.py file INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: If you just do `manage.py test`, does it run tests for myApp?

Comment: It runs a lot of tests but I think it does not detect these tests.

Comment: There was a module named tests I renamed them and the tests started running.